# What is using in visual studio 2012 for convert 3d model .obj

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, 3d-model

In VS 2012 integrated rendering and editor 3d model in *.obj fale.
What is using in VS for convert/import and render 3d model?

Comment: Not sure about your question. I will have a try.  In WPF you define your 3models in the ViewPort3D class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewport3d(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio 2012/2013 [content pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn166877.aspx) for meshes generates a CMO file. This can be loaded by the code in [Visual Studio 3D Starter](http://aka.ms/vs3dkitwin), by the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929), or other implementations.

I'm not aware of any support for CMOs for WPF, although the book [Direct3D Rendering Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849697108) does include C# code for this you could adapt.